# Sometimes why do we have to pass the argument as a tuple in python?

Tags: python, function, methods, tuples

So I wrote this simple program in python which has a function named `num` that takes two arguments as integers and checks if there some is "20" and if it is, then it returns `True` else it returns `False` and you would notice that in `if` statement I have called another function `sum` which is a built-in function in python, So when I try to pass the values of `a`  and `b` in this function without passing them as a ***tuple*** then it gives me the error mentioned below, So my question is that why does it works when I pass them like this `sum((a,b))` and not like this `sum(a,b)`

```
 File "c.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(num(220,10))
  File "c.py", line 3, in num
    if sum(a,b) == 20:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

```
def num(a,b):
    if sum(a,b) == 20:
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(num(220,10))
```

Comment: sum() is a function to sum up all entires in an iterable like list.. so just use the '+' operator (if a + b == 20: ...)

Comment: `sum` expects an iterable (list, tuple...): https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum

Comment: If you are listing the operands, the function is sort of pointless as you can just do `a+b+...+x` and be even more concise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python `sum()` is an inbuilt function that takes an **iterable** and returns the sum of items in it.

So basically you **have to** pass to it an iterable object (as tuple, or list) `sum((a,b))` and not two separate objects `sum(a, b)`.

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple actually, when using
`sum((1,3,4,5,6,7))`
you want it to be as simple as possible, to quickly understand what it'll result.

but as you can see,
`sum(iterable, /, start=0)`
there are more parameters to be used, that you don't have to write them, but they must be passed.

The quick solution? use iterable instead of starred arguments and remove the hassle of knowing the parameters name to skip the defaults (note that starred arguments must be the last args on function signature)

Answer (score 1):

when you are using sum(a,b) it is considering as an a,b as an individual object hence say's "'int' object is not iterable, so we need to pass it as a tuple like sum((a,b)).

Thanks, If you liked my answer please click on "This is useful answer button on side".